# Multi Level Tree UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, expandablelistview

I need to create a facebook like menu. But the difference is, my table have to multi level tree structure.

Please refer the figure to understand the tree structure I mentioned.

I tried with headers as level 0 and cells for both level 1 and level 2. But at last the total code got fussy.Advice Please.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like something I do not really wish to use on a mobile device.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will help you: [KOTree](https://github.com/adamhoracek/KOTree)

The table view will look like this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUjDx.png]

Comment: Great dude, I knew you will come for my help. I will try it and if perfect will come back to accept your answer.

Comment: i knew rashid would have a solution for this..

Comment: Perfect answer... for this to support all orientation add the following to KOTreeViewController.m



    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    
    
 
}

Comment: This is good. But the top levels dont act as headers because they are actually rows. Any way I have found out a solution and custom build it. May be i will add a comment here with its basic logic when I get time.